# How to verify Solaris images in a reliable way?

Tags: solaris

I want to verify my downloaded Solaris installation ISO file, but I can only find MD5 checksums provided by plain http(http://download.oracle.com/otn/solaris/11_3/md5sum.txt), that's not safe enough I think.

How can I get a SHA-256 or higher hash via TLS, from official resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attempt to download the media through MOS Note 1277964.1, you are offered do view digests  in md5 and sha1 in the process. Same when you use edelivery.oracle.com

Both websites use TLS. However you need an Oracle SSO account. MOS needs a valid support identifier, edelivery.oracle.com not.

Comment: I registered an account and it ask me for "Support Identifier", do I have to pay for it?

Comment: Sorry to ask that directly, but you are afraid of downloading a compomised operating system from the original domain, but you want  run it without having  a support aggreement to get security fixes?

Comment: From wikipedia: "When Solaris is used without a support contract it can be upgraded to each new "point release"; however, a support contract is required for access to patches and updates that are released monthly." A small delay of patches seems much less scary to me compare to a compromised OS from beginning.

Comment: Well, the Solaris 11.3 GA release is from October 26th, 2015. I can't talk about the 11.next release. So it's 19 month ago. There was an interesting section in the Verizon DBIR report that stated that within a year of a CVE that went public there will be an exploit. That said i think using a dot release is a good idea for testing playing and so on. But anything that really needs the security of a checksum validated install image should not run unpatched.

Comment: I reaelly think that the perception of risk in this is not really stacked in the right order.

Comment: An md5 validated iso from download.oracle.com is probably the real one.  If you are really afraid of a compromised binary or so keep in mind all binaries in Solaris are cryptographically signed (you can verify it with elfsign -v), there is even a concept of trusted boot allowing only kernel signed by oracle or yourself to boot with SPARC systems from T5 onward. Please keep in mind that a pkg verify can verify all files against SHA1 checksums in the repository of Oracle.

Comment: It's not pratical to verify every file manually, however I guess that's it, we cannot get a secure download without paying, as you said.

Comment: That is not correct. edelivery.oracle.com works without a support identifier ...  and there you can view SHA1 digest as well....

Comment: I tried that and succeed, this should be the real answer. Why didn't you say that in the beginning?

Comment: I did .. " .... Same when you use edelivery.oracle.com". I just wanted to explain that i find your ranking of risks quite strange.

Answer (score -1):

Good luck with that.

Oracle widely distributes MD5 and SHA-1 checksums of install isos but they're really just there to  verify that the file didn't get too mangled on the way.

Perhaps that's best.  A SHA-256 hash from any webserver, TLS or not, doesn't really deliver me anything more than false warm fuzzies.

Sorry if that comes off as harsh or cynical, but unless that file of checksums is gpg signed by somebody I personally know and respect it's about as good as anything I can get on, say, craigslist.